# .htaccess php_value display_errors settings breaks with error 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I installed new XAMPP version 1.8.1 for windows with Apache 2.4.3 and PHP 5.4.7.

None of my sites are working, returning HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error). I traced the reason to this .htaccess line

```
php_value display_errors off
```

When I comment it, site works. I have other php_value command's that works just fine eq. `php_value error_reporting -1`.

Google for solution, people say PHP must be loaded as Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) aka. Apache module. Which in my case is so (httpd-xampp.conf):

```
LoadFile "/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

So this is not what is creating a problem.

I would prefer solution that keeps `php_value display_errors off` inside .htaccess file for the sake of other people it my team.

pls help

**== NEW DEVELOPMENT ==**

After commenting unrelated parts of .htaccess file that was using mod_expires.c and was badly writen, aka. correct way is to put it in if example:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tif|tiff|bmp|png|js|css|ico)$">
       ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

500 error was gone and php_value instructions work.

So if you are in similar situation comment or remove all unrelated lines and try to pint point where the problems is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it should be

```
php_flag   display_errors       Off
```

Not like

```
 php_value   display_errors       Off
```

However, our servers run PHP in "CGI mode" as recommended by the PHP developers (not as an Apache module), so you can't use "php_value" or "php_flag" commands in .htaccess files. If you try to do so, you'll see an "internal server error" message.

Comment: Changing to `php_flag display_errors off` didn't solved the problem. As I said I run PHP as Apache module and setting `php_flag` in .htaccess file should work.

Comment: If it is about the [flag display_errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3448886/1908115) you could just put this line (to debug your php code on a remote server) in a php.ini in the same directory. E.g. I put the two following lines in the php.ini file: `display_errors = On
error_reporting = -1`