# PHPMailer not working on Hostinger, neither any error is displayed

Tags: php, phpmailer, server-configuration

I've hosted a website and there is a contact form. I'm using `PHPMailer` and `Gmail's smtp settings` to send that email. The domain and email are owned by me and I've hosted the domain on **free** hosting service for test.

The email script works fine on my local server, but on Hostinger it displays a Error Page (500), Internal server error. I tried to enable the error logs but still I am not able to see any error.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I've checked the PHP and PHPMailer version on my local server as well as on Hostinger. They are exact same.

Comment: This is really basic debugging - read some docs on how to diagnose PHP problems. If you're getting an error 500, errors will appear in your web server's error log. I expect it's a problem with your host's PHP configuration, not anything wrong with your code.

Comment: But I checked the error logs. They are just blank. Even on enabling them I'm not able to see any logs.

Comment: So try other options to make errors visible: `ini_set('display_errors', true);` etc. If it's generating a 500, it will be generating an error message somewhere!

Comment: @Synchro can you suggest any related blog or article where I can refer to it? Thanks.

Comment: The logs are empty. @Synchro, tried that as well.

Comment: Then echo some output manually - even basic `echo 'got here';` will tell you how far it's got.

Comment: More techniques here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448655/how-to-debug-php-scripts-at-server-side-in-a-situation-client-page-doesnt-show

Comment: Still the same, form takes forever to load. @Synchro

Answer (score 0):

check where is the exact location for the autoload, it may be a folder below:
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.