# How to troubleshoot Occassional 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, html, google-chrome

Forgive me, but I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue.

I built a CMS using PHP/mySQL/jQuery.  I designed and tested it on my local machine for a year.  I've tested it a ridiculous amount of times, and I never had this happen...

I moved the site to my live server.

The site requires a user login.  It's a very big program and has many dependencies that load (jQuery plugins for instance).

Sometimes on a mobile device (iPad, my phone) I get a 500 Server Error and the index/login page does not load at all.  I must clear the cache in my Chrome browser to get it to load.

The site will work fine on my mobile device and then sometimes I get the 500 error again!  So I have to clear the cache again.

I was getting this issue on occasion with my laptop using Chrome, but that seems to have gone away: I don't get that error.  Seems like it's mostly on the mobile devices.  Another user though has to clear his cache on his desktop though randomly.

How do I go about troubleshooting this?  I really appreciate some feedback.  I know I can resolve this.

Comment: Server side logs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448655/how-to-debug-php-scripts-at-server-side-in-a-situation-client-page-doesnt-show

Comment: check the cookies usually they go too big to the level the server cant handle them and that explain why when you clear cache it works

Comment: I only have one cookie stored from the site.  It must be a server error somewhere I guess?  I'll look into the logs.  Thanks.  I'll post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out with your suggestions.

I checked the server's error log, and it seems that I had an error with a cookie that wasn't being stored properly!

So, both of you were correct.

Thanks for taking the time.